# Tomcat Logging on Openshift

Tags: java, log4j, openshift

I have a Java/Spring/JPA app on Openshift.
Locally it works, but when I deploy it I get this unhelpful error in the `jbossews.log` file:

```
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I cannot find out what previous error there were, there are no other logs. So I tried to configure Log4j.

I have this Log4j.properties file in `src/main/resources`:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/lib/openshift/56f1a49d2d5271a846000117/app-root/logs/admin.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

But still the only log file is `jbossews.log` anmd it contains no more information.

How can I work out what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try to ssh to your app and check your `app-root/logs/` folder?

Answer (score 1):

In the .openshift/config/logging.properties replace this:

`org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`

with

`org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`